# ensure forEach loop finishes before next command js

Tags: node.js, express, foreach

Apologies if I'm just being thick. I've tried the search function, but being relatively new to all of this, I'm struggling to work out the solution. I think I'm probably not searching for the right keyword.

I have a route in my Node.js application that has two forEach loops in it. I want forEach loop 1 to finish, then start forEach loop 2. When that finishes, I then want to call my res.redirect. Currently the route is going straight to res.redirect, and doesn't appear to be completing the forEach loops.

Code:

```
// Auto-populate entries
router.post("/populate", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  var baseData = []
  //lookup Plan using ID
  Plan.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundPlan) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/plans");
    } else {
      BaseData.find({
        "contributingRegion": foundPlan.contributingRegion
      }, function(err, foundRecords) {

        foundRecords.forEach(function(record) {
          baseData.push(record)
          baseData.save
        });

        //Create entries & push into plan
        baseData.forEach(function(data) {
          if (includes(req.body.orgs, data.org)) {
            Entry.create(data, function(err, entry) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                entry.author.id = req.user._id;
                entry.author.username = req.user.username;
                entry.save();
                foundPlan.planEntries.push(entry);
                foundPlan.save();
              }
            })
          }
        })

        res.redirect('/plans/' + foundPlan._id);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, for example you could use [promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies) or [async module](https://caolan.github.io/async/), you could also use [recurrent functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/), I will provide a solution with the async module because it let you understand how asynchronous functions work and how to control them:

```
async.each( baseData, function (data, next) {

    if (includes(req.body.orgs, data.org)) {

        Entry.create(data, function(err, entry) {

            if (err) {
                // stop iterating and pass error to the last callback
                next(err);
            } else {
                entry.author.id = req.user._id;
                entry.author.username = req.user.username;
                entry.save();
                foundPlan.planEntries.push(entry);
                foundPlan.save();
                // next iteration
                next();
            }

        });

    } else {
        // next iteration
        next();
    }

}, function (err) {

    // This function runs when all iterations are done

    if (err) throw err;

    res.redirect('/plans/' + foundPlan._id);

} );
```

Comment: Would I need to do an async in the place of the first forEach to call the second async, which then call s the res.send? Sorry, very new to async...

Comment: No you don't, because foreach() is synchronous, you'll get the data populated into `baseData` before the second loop start

Comment: But before all of that you should install and import  async module, read the async docs to know how to use it