# mongoose .create statement not saving inside async.each loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

Following on from my [question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464355/ensure-foreach-loop-finishes-before-next-command-js/), I got the async loop working, but I have run into a new issue. It appears the documents being created by the loop are not being saved to the db. They are however being pushed into the parent record (plan incode below), and that is saving the push successfully. I've included the full route code below:

```
// Auto-populate entries
router.post( "/populate", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  var orgList=[]

  console.log( req.body.orgs);

  if (typeof req.body.orgs == 'string') {
    orgList = [req.body.orgs]
  } else {
    orgList = req.body.orgs
  };

  orgList.save
  console.log( orgList)

  //lookup Plan using ID
  Plan.findById( req.params.id, function(err, foundPlan){
    if(err){
      console.log( err);
      res.redirect("/plans");
    } else {
      BaseData.find({
        "contributingRegion": foundPlan.contributingRegion,
        "org": { $in: orgList}
      }, function( err, baseData) {
        if (err) {
          console.log( err)
        } else {
          console.log( baseData.length);

          //Create entries & push into plan
          async.each( baseData, function(data, next) {
              Entry.create(data, function(err, entry) {             /*Create entry*/
                if(err) {
                  next (err);
                } else {
                  // Create other entry variables
                  entry.author.id = req.user._id;
                  entry.author.username = req.user.username;
                  entry.save();
                  entry.adjHC                  = entry.initHC;
                  entry.adjResRate             = entry.initResRate;
                  entry.yr1Resignations        = Math.round(entry.adjHC * entry.adjResRate);
                  entry.yr1Supply              = entry.adjHC - entry.yr1Resignations;
                  entry.yr2Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr1Supply * entry.adjResRate);
                  entry.yr2Supply              = entry.yr1Supply - entry.yr2Resignations;
                  entry.yr3Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr2Supply * entry.adjResRate);
                  entry.yr3Supply              = entry.yr2Supply - entry.yr3Resignations;
                  entry.yr4Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr3Supply * entry.adjResRate);
                  entry.yr4Supply              = entry.yr3Supply - entry.yr4Resignations;
                  entry.yr5Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr4Supply * entry.adjResRate);
                  entry.yr5Supply              = entry.yr4Supply- entry.yr5Resignations;
                  entry.demandYr0              = entry.adjHC;
                  entry.demandYr1              = entry.adjHC;
                  entry.demandYr2              = entry.adjHC;
                  entry.demandYr3              = entry.adjHC;
                  entry.demandYr4              = entry.adjHC;
                  entry.demandYr5              = entry.adjHC;
                  entry.gapYr1                 = entry.yr1Supply - entry.demandYr1;
                  entry.gapYr2                 = entry.yr2Supply - entry.demandYr2;
                  entry.gapYr3                 = entry.yr3Supply - entry.demandYr3;
                  entry.gapYr4                 = entry.yr4Supply - entry.demandYr4;
                  entry.gapYr5                 = entry.yr5Supply - entry.demandYr5;
                  entry.save();
                  console.log(entry._id + ' saved')
                  foundPlan.planEntries.push(entry);
                  foundPlan.save();
                  // next iteration
                  next();         
                }
              });   /*entry Create*/

          }, function(err) {
            // This function runs when all iterations are done
            if (err) throw err;
            res.redirect('/plans/' + foundPlan._id);
          } );  /*End of Async Loop*/
        };
      });     /*End of BaseDate.find*/
    }         
  });         /*End of Plan.findById*/
});
```

From the various console.logs in the code, that I've been using to troubleshoot, I know the code is finding the right number of entries in baseData (42 records).

I should add the same Entry.create code is used in a separate route where Entries are added manually one-by-one by the user.

When I look at the mongodb itself to look at the size of the planEntries array in the plan I get:

```
// 1) Manually added entry                                                                              
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a6f00421046d90019e2c6e8"), "name" : "test", "numEntries" : 1 }

// 2) After First populate route                                                                             
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a6f00421046d90019e2c6e8"), "name" : "test", "numEntries" : 46 } 

// 3) After a second populate route (same selections)                                                                         
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a6f00421046d90019e2c6e8"), "name" : "test", "numEntries" : 239 }
```

The manually added entry saves correctly, but the others don't seem to be saving the document.

What is also unexpected, is after each auto-populate, I would expect numEmtries to increase by 42, but it seems to be growing by much greater numbers

Comment: Does all those fields that you are ijnserting in `Entry` are inside your `Entry` model as well?

Comment: Yep, all those fields are in my Entry model. All of them are number fields, with the exception of 4 that are passed in as part from the baseData and the author fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So managed to work it out. There were 2 things going on.

Firstly, `Entry.create` creates the object but doesn't allow it to save to the DB for some reason. If i swap my code to be `var entry = new ENTRY()`, then it saved them to the database.

Once I got this working, I ran into an issue of each entry being passed into the plan multiple times (the same number of times as there were entries to add so i ended up with 42 * 42 entries). This was resolved by clearing out the `entry` object before the `next()` function is called. I also switched to `async.eachSeries`. I will test is `async.each` later and see if that works.

UPDATE: `async.each` reverts back to the duplication of results, it appears `async.eachSeries` is needed to prevent this duplication.

Complete final code for completeness:

```
// Auto-populate entries
router.post( "/populate", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function( req, res) {
  // Ensure req.body.orgs is an array
  var orgList=[]

  if (typeof req.body.orgs == 'string') {
    orgList = [req.body.orgs]
  } else {
    orgList = req.body.orgs
  };

  orgList.save

  //lookup Plan using ID
  Plan.findById( req.params.id, function(err, foundPlan){
    if(err){
      console.log( err);
      res.redirect("/plans");
    } else {
      BaseData.find({
        "contributingRegion": foundPlan.contributingRegion,
        "org": { $in: orgList}
      }, function( err, baseData) {
        if (err) {
          console.log( err)
        } else {
          // console.log( baseData.length);

          //Loop through baseData to create entries & push into plan
          async.eachSeries( baseData, function(data, next) {
            console.log(data);
            // Create new entry record
            var entry = new Entry({
              author: {
                id: req.user._id,
                username: req.user.username
              },
              org: data.org,
              jobFamily: data.jobFamily,
              globalGrade: data.globalGrade,
              location: data.location,
              initHC: data.initHC,
              initResRate: data.initResRate.toFixed(3)
            });

            // Derive calculated variables for entry
            entry.adjHC                  = entry.initHC;
            entry.adjResRate             = entry.initResRate;
            entry.yr1Resignations        = Math.round(entry.adjHC * entry.adjResRate);
            entry.yr1Supply              = entry.adjHC - entry.yr1Resignations;
            entry.yr2Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr1Supply * entry.adjResRate);
            entry.yr2Supply              = entry.yr1Supply - entry.yr2Resignations;
            entry.yr3Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr2Supply * entry.adjResRate);
            entry.yr3Supply              = entry.yr2Supply - entry.yr3Resignations;
            entry.yr4Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr3Supply * entry.adjResRate);
            entry.yr4Supply              = entry.yr3Supply - entry.yr4Resignations;
            entry.yr5Resignations        = Math.round(entry.yr4Supply * entry.adjResRate);
            entry.yr5Supply              = entry.yr4Supply- entry.yr5Resignations;
            entry.demandYr0              = entry.adjHC;
            entry.demandYr1              = entry.adjHC;
            entry.demandYr2              = entry.adjHC;
            entry.demandYr3              = entry.adjHC;
            entry.demandYr4              = entry.adjHC;
            entry.demandYr5              = entry.adjHC;
            entry.gapYr1                 = entry.yr1Supply - entry.demandYr1;
            entry.gapYr2                 = entry.yr2Supply - entry.demandYr2;
            entry.gapYr3                 = entry.yr3Supply - entry.demandYr3;
            entry.gapYr4                 = entry.yr4Supply - entry.demandYr4;
            entry.gapYr5                 = entry.yr5Supply - entry.demandYr5;
            entry.save();

            // Push entry into plan
            foundPlan.planEntries.push(entry);
            foundPlan.save(function(err){
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              } else{
                entry = {}
                // next iteration
                next()
              };
            });

          }, function(err) {
            // This function runs when all iterations are done
            if (err) throw err;
            res.redirect('/plans/' + foundPlan._id);
          } );  /*End of Async Loop*/
        };
      });     /*End of BaseDate.find*/
    }         
  });         /*End of Plan.findById*/
});

// =====================================================
// ======UPDATE ENTRIES FROM SUPPLY/DEMAND SCREENS======
// =====================================================

// Entry Update (from Supply Screen)
router.put("/:entryId", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // console.log(req.body)
    var adjHC                  = req.body.entry.adjHC;
    var adjResRate             = req.body.entry.adjResRate / 100;
    var yr1Resignations        = Math.round(adjHC * adjResRate);
    var yr1Supply              = adjHC - yr1Resignations;
    var yr2Resignations        = Math.round(yr1Supply * adjResRate);
    var yr2Supply              = yr1Supply - yr2Resignations;
    var yr3Resignations        = Math.round(yr2Supply * adjResRate);
    var yr3Supply              = yr2Supply - yr3Resignations;
    var yr4Resignations        = Math.round(yr3Supply * adjResRate);
    var yr4Supply              = yr3Supply - yr4Resignations;
    var yr5Resignations        = Math.round(yr4Supply * adjResRate);
    var yr5Supply              = yr4Supply- yr5Resignations;
    var demandYr0              = adjHC;
    var demandYr1              = adjHC;
    var demandYr2              = adjHC;
    var demandYr3              = adjHC;
    var demandYr4              = adjHC;
    var demandYr5              = adjHC;
    var gapYr1                 = yr1Supply - demandYr1;
    var gapYr2                 = yr2Supply - demandYr2;
    var gapYr3                 = yr3Supply - demandYr3;
    var gapYr4                 = yr4Supply - demandYr4;
    var gapYr5                 = yr5Supply - demandYr5;

    var updatedEntry = {adjHC           : adjHC, 
                        adjResRate      : adjResRate,
                        yr1Resignations : yr1Resignations,
                        yr2Resignations : yr2Resignations,
                        yr3Resignations : yr3Resignations,
                        yr4Resignations : yr4Resignations,
                        yr5Resignations : yr5Resignations,
                        yr1Supply       : yr1Supply,
                        yr2Supply       : yr2Supply,
                        yr3Supply       : yr3Supply,
                        yr4Supply       : yr4Supply,
                        yr5Supply       : yr5Supply,
                        demandYr0       : demandYr0,
                        demandYr1       : demandYr1,
                        demandYr2       : demandYr2,
                        demandYr3       : demandYr3,
                        demandYr4       : demandYr4,
                        demandYr5       : demandYr5,
                        gapYr1          : gapYr1,
                        gapYr2          : gapYr2,
                        gapYr3          : gapYr3,
                        gapYr4          : gapYr4,
                        gapYr5          : gapYr5            };

   //lookup Entry using ID
    Entry.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.entryId, updatedEntry, {new: true}, function(err, foundEntry){
       if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/plans");
       } else {
            res.json(foundEntry);
        }
    });
});
```